# ColdFusion: Is it possible to get the index from a cfscript for in loop?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

So I'm iterating through an array of structs using a for in loop

```
for(item in array) {
    processStruct(item)
}
```

Pretty straightforward, What I'm trying to do is get the current index in the for in loop and pass it along as well to the function: `processStruct(item, index)`. I know I can do this with a regular for loop and it's also possible with the tag version `<cfloop>`

```
<cfloop array="#myArray#" index="i">
    #i#
<cfloop>
```

Answer (score 4):

The tag variant `<cfloop>` offers item and index starting with ColdFusion 2016 (or Railo/Lucee).

```
<cfset x = [ "a", "b", "c" ]>
<cfloop array="#x#" index="idx" item="it">
    <cfoutput>#idx#:#it#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
<!--- returns 1:a 2:b 3:c --->
```

All ColdFusion versions prior to 2016 do not, so you would have to do it by yourself:

```
<cfset x = [ "a", "b", "c" ]>
<cfset idx = 1>
<cfloop array="#x#" index="it">
    <cfoutput>#idx#:#it#</cfoutput>
    <cfset idx++>
</cfloop>
<!--- returns 1:a 2:b 3:c --->
```

The script variant doesn't support it and most likely never will. [Java's Iterator interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) doesn't offer it either.

Comment: The script variant of cfloop does support index in Lucee:
https://trycf.com/gist/b60987764fb9ba9f2292ba2fbdd48e91/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: I was referring to the `for(x in a)` script variant mentioned in the the start post. You just showed the cfscript version of the cfloop tag.

Comment: Ah, you might want to edit your answer then.  It wasn't clear which 'script variant' you were referring to.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have an index on the for ... in loop. Just set an index of your own:

```
var idx = 1;
for( item in struct ){
    processStruct( item, idx );
    idx++;
}
```

Comment: Either idx should start at 0, or the two lines in the loop are in the wrong order.

Comment: Right? I guess that's what happens in the middle of the night. Thx for the heads up.

Comment: You could also remove the `idx++;` line and use `processStruct( item, idx++ );` if `idx = 1`, or `processStruct( item, ++idx );` if `idx = 0`

Answer (score 2):

As of CF11 you can use a member function. That way you have access to both the element and the index:

```
myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
// By arrayEach() member function CF11+
myArray.each(function(element, index) {
    writeOuput(element & " : " & index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (where i is your array index):

```
for (i=1; i lte ArrayLen(yourArray); i++){
     processStruct(yourArray[i],i);
}
```

Comment: The last sentence of the question stated that he already knew how to use this approach.  Hence the downvote.